# online Ukrainian test to check my progress in learning the language?

Tags: discussion

(Not sure if this is on-topic here but I thought I'd try.)

I've been learning Ukrainian for a few months and just realized I don't have any way to "objectively" (of course nothing is really objective, but still) see my progress. I think it would help my motivation if I could see how much better I'm doing - I often feel like I haven't gotten very far even though I suspect I have. Can anyone recommend a good online test I could re-take once in a while to see if I've gotten better?

Preferably one that isn't based on choosing words from a list, or at least the choice is actually difficult (grammatical forms or otherwise similar words rather than just giving you random words to pick from like e.g. Duolingo does) - I speak Polish, so I can often guess a lot if I'm given a sufficiently limited and obvious word-list, and I'd like to be able to see by the test result to what extent I've progressed from guessing things to knowing them.

Comment: Related post (as [mentioned](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/6980#comment12293_6980) by bytebuster): [Онлайн-тести на знання українскої мови](/q/187) (“Online tests for knowledge of the Ukrainian language”).

Comment: I've added new entries into [this answer](/a/200). (However, please be aware that most of these test are oriented onto the native speakers of Ukrainian.)

Answer (score -1):

***Answer Intro:*** To entirely answer the question, I post this my text here, as an answer to the question.

---

### Main text.

Yea, **this** is a '**meta**' purpose, nor the exact other, **not** the community "Ukrainian". Would be *great* to post there, if you still require the need of answer to this question, and an appropriate answer does not exist yet (again, on Meta).
The link to the corresponding question on 'meta' is not required to be posted here, but you may add it via either *edit*, or *a comment* to your question here: if posted, put the words '*I have posted the respective question on <url/link>*'.

Best wishes *in* and *with* learning the Ukrainian language!
Успіхів (у вивченні української мови), шановна! :-).

---

### Appendix.

In addition, about learning the Ukrainian language **for *you***. You may speak with Ukrainians, it is a good practice, and you may switch your important lines, such as devices languages (if you use devices a lot), to the Ukrainian. *Best wishes one more time, і бажаю успіхів Вам у навчанні!*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3668)

Answer (score -1):

This is very useful application for check your ukrainian level.

https://www.arealme.com/ukrainian-vocabulary-size-test/uk/

My individual record 26996, try to improve it!
[image]